# PDOException in Connection.php line 358: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, exception, pdo

I have tried so many different ways to solve this problem but nothing seems to be working. How do I fix it?
I tried: -setting auto increment for table.
-reinstalling php laravel, re-installing and checking all the configuration of PHP
-Clearning php artisan cache, config.. etc
-Refreshing php artisan.
-Making sure the file permissions are correct (root and apache has permissions to read)

Let me know if I need to include anything else neccessary. Thanks in advance.

my env:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=66ixWFPHjUmrFykF3mBw2nfpFPiqLGGe
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=daily

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=streaming_new
DB_USERNAME=myuser
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Connection.php file:
[enter link description here](https://pastebin.com/hbWsSzWU)

[image: Error img:]

Update: Whenever I use `php artisan migrate:refresh` this shows: [migrate error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymmOY.png)

Comment: can you share connection.php with us please?

Comment: Sure
updating now

Comment: Your table `video_video_category` does not have a default value for the `ID` column. Did you create the migration with Laravel? If so, show that. If not, then you'll need to update your table to have the ID be auto_increment, if that's what you want.

Comment: Can you show us the migration file of the table? The log obviously shows that you don't insert an id value

Comment: If you are using the `DB` facade you will need to call: `insertGetId()` to insert a corresponding id value: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#auto-incrementing-ids

Comment: @aynber Yes i did, and it had done it successfully, I just updated the post check the error that shows when i try to refresh, when i use migrate:status it says no migrations founds.

Comment: Also I want to add, I have the same laravel project working on another server, I just need to move it to another one, I installed laravel, and used the same database and laravel project files, I edited .env key but, is there anything else do to? Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a guess from the error and say that you need to set your primary key in your model to be 'video_id'.  Laravel presumes all model ID's to be 'id', hence the error message mentioning 'id', but it looks like you are using 'video_id' as your model ID.

You are going to need something like this at the top of your model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'video_id';
```